# Django FormWizard how to change the form_list dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm able [to dynamically call one form related to the data I chose from the step ealier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836547/dynamic-formwizard/18999160#18999160).

But when I'm in the `done` method I can see the my `form_list` is remaining unchanged.

here is what I did :

```
def get_form_list(request, form_list=None):
    if form_list is None:
        form_list = [ProviderForm, DummyForm, ConsummerForm, DummyForm, \
                 ServicesDescriptionForm]
    return UserServiceWizard.as_view(form_list=form_list)(request)


class UserServiceWizard(SessionWizardView):
    instance = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.form_list = kwargs.pop('form_list')
        return super(UserServiceWizard, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = UserService()
        return self.instance

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(self.get_prev_step(
                                                    self.steps.current))
        if self.steps.current == '1':
            service_name = str(data['provider']).split('Service')[1]
            form = class_for_name('th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms',
                                  service_name + 'ProviderForm')
            self.form_list['1'] = form #here my form is correctly change I can see 

        elif self.steps.current == '3':
            service_name = str(data['consummer']).split('Service')[1]
            form = class_for_name('th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms',
                                  service_name + 'ConsummerForm')
            self.form_list['3'] = form

        context = super(UserServiceWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form,
                                                              **kwargs)
        return context


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        print self.form_list #here form_list contains ProviderForm, DummyForm, ConsummerForm, DummyForm, ServicesDescriptionForm
```

at step 0 my form_list is ok :

```
{u'0': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.ProviderForm'>, 
u'1': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.DummyForm'>, 
u'2': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.ConsummerForm'>, 
u'3': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.DummyForm'>, 
u'4': <class 'django_th.forms.base.ServicesDescriptionForm'>}
```

at step 1 my form_list is ok : we can see the 2nd form is my expected one

```
{u'0': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.ProviderForm'>, 
u'1': <class 'th_rss.forms.RssProviderForm'>, 
u'2': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.ConsummerForm'>, 
u'3': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.DummyForm'>, 
u'4': <class 'django_th.forms.base.ServicesDescriptionForm'>}
```

at step 2 my form_list is ko ; same as step 0 : my 2nd form is return to DummyForm

```
{u'0': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.ProviderForm'>, 
u'1': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.DummyForm'>, 
u'2': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.ConsummerForm'>,
u'3': <class 'django_th.forms.wizard.DummyForm'>, 
u'4': <class 'django_th.forms.base.ServicesDescriptionForm'>}
```

How can I do to change self.form_list and keep the change I did in `get_context_data` until the end of the wizard and not at each step ?

**EDIT**
here is the complete code that works fine with the Rohan's suggestion :

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    """
        change the form instance dynamically from the data we entered
        at the previous step
    """
    if step is None:
        step = self.steps.current

    if step == '1':
        # change the form
        prev_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        service_name = str(prev_data['provider']).split('Service')[1]
        class_name = 'th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms'
        form_name = service_name + 'ProviderForm'
        form_class = class_for_name(class_name, form_name)
        form = form_class(data)
    elif step == '3':
        # change the form
        prev_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('2')
        service_name = str(prev_data['consummer']).split('Service')[1]
        class_name = 'th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms'
        form_name = service_name + 'ConsummerForm'
        form_class = class_for_name(class_name, form_name)
        form = form_class(data)
    else:
        # get the default form
        form = super(UserServiceWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
    return form

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    """
        Save info to the DB
        The process is :
        1) get the infos for the Trigger from step 0, 2, 4
        2) save it to TriggerService
        3) get the infos from the "Provider" and "Consummer" services
        at step 1 and 3
        4) save all of them
    """
    # get the datas from the form for TriggerService
    i = 0
    for form in form_list:
        # cleaning
        data = form.cleaned_data
        # get the service we selected at step 0 : provider
        if i == 0:
            trigger_provider = UserService.objects.get(
                name=data['provider'],
                user=self.request.user)
            model_provider = get_service_model('provider', data)
        # get the service we selected at step 2 : consummer
        elif i == 2:
            trigger_consummer = UserService.objects.get(
                name=data['consummer'],
                user=self.request.user)
            model_consummer = get_service_model('consummer', data)
        # get the description we gave for the trigger
        elif i == 4:
            trigger_description = data['description']
        i += 1

    # save the trigger
    trigger = TriggerService(
        provider=trigger_provider, consummer=trigger_consummer,
        user=self.request.user, status=True,
        description=trigger_description)
    trigger.save()

    model_fields = {}
    # get the datas from the form for Service related
    # save the related models to provider and consummer
    i = 0
    for form in form_list:
        model_fields = {}
        data = form.cleaned_data
        # get the data for the provider service
        if i == 1:
            for field in data:
                model_fields.update({field: data[field]})
            model_fields.update({'trigger_id': trigger.id, 'status': True})
            model_provider.objects.create(**model_fields)
        # get the data for the consummer service
        elif i == 3:
            for field in data:
                model_fields.update({field: data[field]})
            model_fields.update({'trigger_id': trigger.id, 'status': True})
            model_consummer.objects.create(**model_fields)
        i += 1

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of changing form list etc. in `get_context_data()`, I think more appropriate will be to implement `get_form()` method in your wizard view and return different form instance depending upon the step and previous data.

Something like this:

```
class UserServiceWizard(SessionWizardView):
    instance = None

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current

        prev_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(self.get_prev_step(
                                                    self.steps.current))
        if step == '1':
            service_name = str(prev_data['provider']).split('Service')[1]
            form_class = class_for_name('th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms',
                                  service_name + 'ProviderForm')
            form = form_class(data)
        elif step == '3':
            service_name = str(prev_data['consummer']).split('Service')[1]
            form_class = class_for_name('th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms',
                                  service_name + 'ConsummerForm')
            form = form_class(data)
        else:
            form = super(UserServiceWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)

        return form
```

The trick here is do not change the length of form list (which you have done correctly), but just change form instance. Django has provided way to override `get_form()` method for this purpose. Django will honor this method and always use it to get the form instance for the method.

Comment: for you for your reply. I try it. I made some test with get_form too but with no success. In fact I test so many solution with each function of the form wizard that i finish by seeing nothing.

Comment: So i drop my get_context_data, and my first test returns no data at step1 ; prev_data is empy so prev_data['provider'] fails with `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Yeah ! i've almost reached the goal. I will confirm soon !

Comment: @FoxMaSk, don't think that error is related. May be you can post your actual code, if you still get that error.

Comment: I valid your answer and thank you for your help. Now i have other problem but the main one here is solved !

Comment: I thought that when I validated, that will give you the expected bounty. It's my first one :-) i didnt know that I had to explicitly check it too ;)

Comment: i've edited my ask with the complete code that works now perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the solution you are looking for, but if you modify form_list in process_step instead of in get_context_data it should work. You will have to change your code since process_step is executed after a form is submitted.

According to Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/ process_step is the "Hook for modifying the wizard’s internal state", at least for self.kwargs vars (in fact your form_list is in self.kwargs["form_list"]) I have tested that all modifications in get_context_data are ignored so I think that self.form_list should behave in the same way.

Comment: I put pdb in the loop to track what is the path followed by the Wizard.So 1rst is `__init__`of course ;) followed by `get_context_data` and finally by `process_step` except for the last step, where the path becomes `__init__` then `process_step` then `done`. But on my side the only function that let me change the form on the fly is not `process_step` but `get_context_data`. process_step does noting ...