# Django FormWizard infinite loop

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I use Django 1.4.8

[I am able to dynamically change the form from a choice made on the previous step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068452/django-formwizard-how-to-change-the-form-list-dynamically), but now I need to be more accurate.

Effectively, in my form "step 0", I have a dropdown from where I select a value, then at step 2, I need to load the same data as "step 0" without the selected value at step 0.

I did it like this :

**urls.py** :

```
# wizard
url(r'^service/create/$',
    UserServiceWizard.as_view([ProviderForm,
                               DummyForm,
                               ConsummerForm,
                               DummyForm,
                               ServicesDescriptionForm]),
```

**views.py**

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    """
        change the form instance dynamically from the data we entered
        at the previous step
    """
    #
    if step is None:
        step = self.steps.current

    if step == '1':

        prev_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        service_name = str(prev_data['provider']).split('Service')[1]
        class_name = 'th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms'
        form_name = service_name + 'ProviderForm'
        form_class = class_for_name(class_name, form_name)
        form = form_class(data)

    elif step == '2':
        data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        form = ConsummerForm(initial={'provider': data['provider']})

        # EDIT 10/16 @ 10:00 
        # to track what's wrong I added 
        print form['consummer'].errors #return nothing 
        print form.is_valid() #return false
        print "form.non_field_errors ", form.non_field_errors() #return nothing


    elif step == '3':

        prev_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('2')
        service_name = str(prev_data['consummer']).split('Service')[1]
        class_name = 'th_' + service_name.lower() + '.forms'
        form_name = service_name + 'ConsummerForm'
        form_class = class_for_name(class_name, form_name)
        form = form_class(data)

    else:
        form = super(UserServiceWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)

    return form
```

my **forms** is :

```
class ServiceChoiceForm(forms.Form):

    def activated_services(self, provider=None):
        """
        get the activated services added from the administrator
        """
        services = ServicesActivated.objects.filter(status=1)

        choices = []
        datas = ()

        if provider is not None:
            services = services.exclude(name__exact=provider)

        for class_name in services:
            datas = (class_name, class_name.name.rsplit('Service', 1)[1])
            choices.append(datas)

        return choices

class ProviderForm(ServiceChoiceForm):

    provider = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProviderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['provider'].choices = self.activated_services()


class ConsummerForm(ServiceChoiceForm):

    consummer = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConsummerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # get the list of service without the one selected in
        # the provider form
        self.fields['consummer'].choices = self.activated_services(
            self.initial['provider'])
```

Now what's happened :

when I'm on the form "step 2" and submit the data... I return to "step 2" indefinitely

If I dont put the part of `elif step == '2'` in the `get_form()` and put the same code in the form form the ConsummerForm :

```
self.fields['consummer'].choices = self.activated_services()
```

then  the process continues but it's not what I want :(

**last things**
"=
I notice that the `get_form()` is called too many times after the "step 0" : in fact 4 times . 
I tracked that with a `print form,step` in `get_form()` but the form is never the expected one.

If anyone can explain my how I can fix the behavior of the infite loop in the wizard ; i would appreciate a lot ;)

Comment: The things you do with django form wizard never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Imagine once it will work :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about very localized problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

at step 2 I have to do this

```
    elif step == '2':
        step0_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        form = ConsummerForm(
            data, initial={'provider': step0_data['provider']})
```

instead of

```
    elif step == '2':
        data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
        form = ConsummerForm(initial={'provider': data['provider']})
```

because In the 1rst I didnt overwrite the "data" dict like i did by accident in 2nd piece of code...

now everything works GREAT !